# Where like query result not as expected

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

i have written eloquent query to get search input result with some conditions, but the result are not as expected

```
//i have 4 drivers registered by agent_id 12 in that 2 are pending registrations on searching name of the driver i should get only of those pending 


        public function pendingRegistrationSearch($agent_id, $search_input, $limit)
        {
            $pending_registration_search = Driver::where('agent_id' , $agent_id)
                 ->where('registration_status', 'pending')
                 ->orwhere('id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
                 ->orwhere('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
                 ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
                 ->orWhere('phone_number', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
                 ->orWhere('registration_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
                 ->select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_status')
                     ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
                 ->limit(30)->offset($limit)
                 ->get();

            return Response::json([
                'data' => $pending_registration_search
            ]); 
        }

    //but i'm getting all the data based on search result, data have the drivers of all the agents too

     {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "first_name": "Ajay",
          "last_name": "singh",
          "phone_number": "1234568790",    data of agent_id 10
          "registration_status": "pending"
        }, 
       {
          "id": 2,
          "first_name": "john",
          "last_name": "machado",
          "phone_number": "1234568790",       data of agent_id 12
          "registration_status": "processed"
        }
      ]
    }
```

i guess the 1st two where condition is not working

thank you

Comment: "not working" is not a working problem description. Put up a real [mcve] !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't give you probably exact solution, but the problem is probably that you don't apply some conditions. when you use `orWhere` you usually should wrap the whole condition into closure for example:

```
   $pending_registration_search = Driver::where('agent_id' , $agent_id)
         ->where(function($q) use ($search_input) {
            $q->where('registration_status', 'pending')
            ->orwhere('id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
            ->orwhere('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
            ->orWhere('phone_number', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
            ->orWhere('registration_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
         })->select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_status')
             ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
         ->limit(30)->offset($limit)
         ->get();
```

For example in above `agent_id` condition will be always used and others will be created using OR, so you will get now query like this:

```
WHERE A AND (B OR C OR D)
```

In your version of where you were doing:

```
WHERE A AND B OR C OR D
```

what is same as:

```
WHERE (A AND B) OR C OR D
```

so if C or D conditions where true, A condition was not used at all.

Based on you wrote it's also possible you want to use:

```
   $pending_registration_search = Driver::where('agent_id' , $agent_id)  
         ->where('registration_status', 'pending')
         ->where(function($q) use ($search_input) {
            $q->where('id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
            ->orwhere('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
            ->orWhere('phone_number', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
            ->orWhere('registration_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
         })->select('id','first_name','last_name','phone_number','registration_status')
             ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
         ->limit(30)->offset($limit)
         ->get();
```

Comment: thank you so much for you time, i used your solution by passing `->where(function($q) use ($search_input)` and the result is same i'm getting the `registration_status=processed` data too, and data of other `agent_id`

Comment: @MrRobot Look at my 2nd example in answer. In this you will get only drivers for thos agent with pending status that will match the search condition

Comment: thank you so much, 2nd example is working, i really appreciate you time

Comment: can you please tell me if no data i wan to return some custom message in json

Comment: @MrRobot It's enough to add condition for exmple: `if ($pending_registration_search) { // here you return response if there is data} else { // here you return response if there is no data}

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is here:

```
where('agent_id' , $agent_id)
->where('registration_status', 'pending')
->orwhere('id', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
```

Lets understand with this:

```
( 'agent_id' = $agent_id ) && ( 'registration_status' = 'pending' )
|| ( condition ) || ( condition ) || ( condition ) || ( condition )
```

this kind of relationship is working here, but you need:

```
( ( 'agent_id' = $agent_id ) && ( 'registration_status' = 'pending' ) )
    || (( condition ) || ( condition ) || ( condition ) || ( condition ) )
```

this type of relationship. So I think you can use `RAW query` here.

Comment: thank you for your time, i want a way to do in eloquent, is there a solution to achieve this, i want to get all the search result only if the passed `agent_id` and `registration_status` is pending